# HTTPS for SpringBoot Application on Ubuntu Server (Hosted on STRATO)

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

i try to develop my SpringBoot Backend Application on STRATO.de

i buyed a ubunutu vServer and runned my spring app via jar.

but backend (http) and frontend (https) cant connect because of the ssl. I created a self signed jks file for my spring boot app and the https works but when i open my backend ip adress and port firstly i get the message "this ist not a secure connection" and i have to accept the certificate. After that everything works fine.

Is there a Option to get a secure connection? i try to use LetsEncrypt CerBot etc. nothing works. The Tutorials are not for the newest Ubuntu version.

Where can i secure my SpringBoot app via HTTPS without a SelfSigned certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Both frontend & backend needs to have https connection for secured communication. Hence it's necessary to use https for your spring-boot application. Self signed jks is only good for development, which is not meant to be used for production.

You may follow these steps:

1. Install `OpenSSL` if not available in your server. [How to install OpenSSL](https://fedingo.com/how-to-install-openssl-in-ubuntu/)
2. Run this command, `# openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourkey.key -out yourcsr.csr`
   Here, **yourkey.key** = It’s your private key and
   **yourcsr.csr** = Your Certificate Signing Request which needs to send to CA authorities. While creating CSR, it will ask some questions, which will be later required for keystore. Hence, save them properly.
3. Buy your SSL certificate from your preferable registrant, ie name.com
4. Send your **yourcsr.csr** file information to the registrants. Please follow their respective instructions.
5. Once approved, you will receive two files. **yourserver.crt** and **yourca.crt**
6. `# openssl pkcs12 -export -in yourserver.crt -inkey yourkey.key -out yourkeystore.p12 -name somealias -certfile yourca.crt -caname root`
   It will ask some questions, pls make sure it matches the information that you provided earlier while creating the CSR. It will prompt for password for the keystore. This command will create a keystore named yourkeystore.p12
7. `# keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore yourkeystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore yourkeystore.jks -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass newkeystorepassword -destkeypass newkeypassword` Convert to JKS, if you specifically want to use JKS for spring boot. This command will create a keystore named yourkeystore.jks
8. Put required information at `application.properties`.

   ```
   server.port: 8443
   server.ssl.key-store: classpath: yourkeystore.jks
   server.ssl.key-store-password: newkeystorepassword
   server.ssl.key-store-type: jks
   server.ssl.key-alias: somealias
   server.ssl.key-password: newkeypassword
   ```